# Telegram Bot Checks Rather Mentions Is User Or Group Chat

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to code a python anti-advertising telegram bot and basically want to check when a user mentions another user in their message it will check rather the mentioned @ is a user or a group.

I want the members to still be able to mention other usernames like ex: @username, but when they mention a group @testinggroup, it will be flagged and removed, here's all I have right now.

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import * 
from requests import *
import re

updater = Updater(token="bot_token", use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

username = re.compile(r'^@[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]{4,30}$', re.IGNORECASE)

def messageHandler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):

    #chat_member = context.bot.get_chat_member(update.effective_chat.id, update.message.from_user.id)
    #if chat_member.status == 'creator' or chat_member.status == 'administrator' or chat_member.user.is_bot:
    #    return
 
    if username.search(update.message.text):
        return #NEED HELP HERE

dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, messageHandler))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

I've tried everything,
tried removing messages with @ in them, but I want users to still be able to mention each other.
tried using regex to detect usernames, but once again want users to be able to mention each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Checking if a message contains a mention

Note that you can use [`Filters.entity("mention")`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.15/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.entity) to filter for messages that contain a mention in the form `@username` - that way you don't have to rely on regex.

Moreover, you can retrieve the usernames via [`update.effective_message.parse_entities(["mention"])`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.15/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.parse_entities).
Note that [`MessageEntity.user`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#messageentity) is *not* available for entities of type `"mention"`.

#### Checking if a username links to a private chat or something else

As implied by [Lorenzo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74981720/10606962), you can use `get_chat` for this. Note that `get_chat` should return the `Chat` object in case the username links to a public group or channel. However, for private chats, `get_chat` only works with the user id and not the username, so `get_chat("@privateusername")` will raise a "Chat not found" exception rather than returning a `Chat` object.

---

Note: The links point to the PTB v13.15 docs. The current stable version is v20.0, which contains significant breaking changes compared to v13.x.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.